# error CS0139: No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue

Tags: c#, break

Here is my C# coding

```
public string RemoveFirstSpaces (string str)
{
    if(str.Length > 0)
    {
        while(str[0] == " ")
        {
            str = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1);
            if(str.Length <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

How could i break when it comes inside the if stmt..

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The code you've given compiles, albeit with a warning on `str[0] == null` (as `str[0]` is a `char`, which can never be `null`).

Comment: Sry, Its should not be null it is while(str[0] == " ")

Comment: Just to check, you are aware of `String.TrimStart()`, right? But this still doesn't change my general point - there's no point in asking why you're getting an error, but then posting code which doesn't show that error.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the reply. Sorry for my mistake. will correct it in my future posts. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, the only mistake is the check in the `while` it should be:

```
 while (str[0] == ' ')
```

since `str[0]` is a character and currently you are comparing it with `" "` which is string.

Although a simpler way to remove starting space would be to use [String.TrimeStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx)

```
public string RemoveFirstSpaces (string str)
{
  return str.TrimStart();
}
```